# Why isn't my gulp task running?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm using the following code because grabbing the whole `js` folder won't honor file sequence. So I select file by file, but it won't produce the `site.min.js` file even though no error is given.

```
gulp.task("minjs", function () {
  gulp.src([
      'js/site.js',
      'js/directives/navbar.js',
      'js/directives/Select.Lang.js'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('site.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/js/"));
});
```

**Updated:**

No, it's not the return. I tried that too.  I also searched trough my PC if a file was generated, but there's no file and the weirdest thing is that the gulp task shows no error.

Comment: After hours of drilling, i wasn't receiving errors but i wasn't generating a file. and that was because i was graving nothing. I was missing wwwroot/ because the modules are on the root of all so i had to include wwwroot

Answer (score -1):

Notice the `return` statement:

```
gulp.task("minjs", function () {
  return gulp.src([
    'js/site.js',
    'js/directives/navbar.js',
    'js/directives/Select.Lang.js'
  ])
  .pipe(concat('site.min.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/js/"));
});
```

Comment: Is this actually the answer? I thought having it return just made it synchronous, didn't know that it wouldn't work without it

Comment: gulp tasks go really strange if you run async tasks without the return.  It is, at the very least, the first thing to fix.  If that fails, you'll need to update your question with more information.

Comment: True, I have noticed that. I'm not the OP, but definitely want to know the answer myself haha